# Retrieve image from S3 bucket matching a pattern (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, amazon-s3, preg-match

I have an S3 bucket full of images whose naming follows a simple pattern. The first 6 digits group images by listing number, the trailing digit(s) are non-sequential, but follow a reliable pattern (0 thru 99) I'm capturing the six digits that start the filename in a variable `$ln`.

```
/*
https://s3.amazonaws.com/stroupenwmls2/602665_10.jpg
https://s3.amazonaws.com/stroupenwmls2/602665_12.jpg
https://s3.amazonaws.com/stroupenwmls2/602665_13.jpg
https://s3.amazonaws.com/stroupenwmls2/602665_15.jpg
*/
```

What I want to do is populate a 'listing' img src attribute with the url to an image, if one exists for that listing (if not, I provide a no-image.jpg). And I'm looping thru many different listings to create my web page.

I'm struggling with the logic to grab the first image that matches the $listing variable. Here is what I've tried, with no luck (just produces a 0):

```
$bucket = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/stroupenwmls2/';
$ln = '602665';
$string = $bucket . $ln . '_';
// match the pattern '_xx.jpg', with 1 or 2 numbers
$image = preg_match('/^_[0-9]{1,2}\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/i', $string);
```

Then in my web app:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
```

I'm an idiot when it comes to using preg_match, what I really need is some sort of wildcard parameter. I'm sure I'm making this way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not matching against the image paths, you're matching against what i assume you intend to be part of your regular expression. See below:

```php
$bucket = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/stroupenwmls2/';
$ln = '602665';
$re = $bucket . $ln . '_' + '[0-9]{1,2}\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)';

// let's say you have an array called img_list;
// loop through each path in the list, searching strings
// that match the regular expression constructed in $re.
// if you find a match, return it.
// you'd probably want to define a function to do this for you,
// and call it with the $listing and array as parameters.

foreach (img_list as $img) {
  // this returns either 0 or 1 depending on match.
  // return the first one, and we're done.
  if (preg_match('/^' . $re . '/i', $img)) {
    return $img;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I included a sample of those images at the beginning of my question. The S3 bucket has thousands of images, if one (or more) exists that matches the first 6 numbers, I want to grab one to show in my web app.